# Why don't the glyphs line up if they're in the same Graphics?

Tags: fonts, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to overlay glyphs from different fonts, but it's hard to get them to line up.  I'm sure they ought to line up better than this. How can I do that?

```
Graphics[
   {Opacity[0.1],
      {Text[Style["a", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 240]],
       Text[Style["a", FontFamily -> "Arial", 240]]}
   }]
```

Also, I'm interested in drawing the outline - here I've selected them, but I'd like to draw them.

[image: Screenshot]

Edit: Thanks! With your help I was able to achieve most of what I was trying to:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{{{Opacity[opacity], 
     Text[Style["Greats", Red, FontFamily -> "Helvetica",  180], {0, 
       0}, {Center, Baseline}]}, {Opacity[1 - opacity], 
     Text[Style["Greats", Blue, FontFamily -> "Arial", 180],  {0, 
       0}, {Center, Baseline}]}}}], {opacity, 0.1, 1, 0.1}]
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default the text is centered (horizontally and vertically) at a point, and the fonts have characters of different heights, resulting in shifted text.  For example compare the following:

```
Graphics[{Opacity[
   0.1], {Text[
    Style["agÄ", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 240, 
     Background -> RGBColor[0.8, 0, 0, 0.2]]], 
   Text[Style["agÄ", FontFamily -> "Arial", 240, 
     Background -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0.8, 0.2]]]}
  }]
Graphics[{Opacity[
   0.1], {Text[
    Style["agA", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 240, 
     Background -> RGBColor[0.8, 0, 0, 0.2]]], 
   Text[Style["agA", FontFamily -> "Arial", 240, 
     Background -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0.8, 0.2]]]}
  }]
```

[image]

If you position the text along an edge, it might work better for you, although it's by no means guaranteed:

```
Graphics[{Opacity[
   0.1], {Text[
    Style["a", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 240], {0, 0}, {Center, 
     Bottom}], 
   Text[Style["a", FontFamily -> "Arial", 240], {0, 0}, {Center, 
     Bottom}]}}]
```

[image]

**Edit**
Using `Baseline` as suggested by Heike:

```
Graphics[{Opacity[
   0.1], {Text[
    Style["a", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 240], {0, 0}, {Center, 
     Baseline}], 
   Text[Style["a", FontFamily -> "Arial", 240], {0, 0}, {Center, 
     Baseline}]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Using `Baseline` instead of `Bottom` for the offset in the vertical direction might even work better.

Comment: @Heike Good point, especially since this setting is underdocumented.  (I looked for this a bit before I answered but didn't find it in the `Text` docs.)

Comment: There is an example using this setting in the `BaseLine` documentation.

Comment: Thanks, though i dont like how the first graphic is so much better than the second! I'm sure the glyphs have very similar metrics, so i would expect them to line up as well as they do in the first graphic.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding your first question, welcome to the world of different fonts. They have different metrics and that is just how it is. You could use `Overlay` or one of the graphics options like `ImagePadding` to shift one over the other.

On your second question, the second "neat example" in the [documentation on `JoinedCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/JoinedCurve.html) shows how to do this using `ExportString` and `ImportString`.